# How to get the complete HTML output of action inside controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a way how I can get a complete HTML output of a controller action? Is there some method for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down to the very bottom of this page for an example:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/howto-capture-action-output-stream-it-as-pdf-td671222.html

Answer (score 3):

```
$html = $this->view->render('view.phtml');
```

I think you should be able to also get this by playing with the response object.

like :

```
$this->getResponse()->getBody();
```

Answer (score 2):

Action view helper may be useful, from [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html):

```
  <div id="sidebar right">
   <div class="item">
    <?php echo $this->action('list',
                             'comment',
                             null,
                             array('count' => 10)); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can replace echo with storing the var or do it outside of the view script.